# Multiple cookies in CookieManager

Tags: android, cookies, android-webview, android-cookiemanager

Lets prepare for cookie storing:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getApplicationContext());
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
```

Then I'm putting manually some cookies, lets say `PHPSESSID` and `RANDOM`

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie("domain.com", "PHPSESSID="+phpSession);
CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie("domain.com", "RANDOM="+random);
```

lets check is it working using:

```
CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie("domain.com");
```

and got

```
PHPSESSID=dba4ff392agd39b5951d10a91a0a7b56; RANDOM=266284790:1466147978:c91d0896bac59e0b
```

Everything looks good, but when I navigate in may app to one of `WebView` Activities, which are opening same domain website also setting cookies, then when I print cookie like above it looks like this:

```
PHPSESSID=dba4ff392agd39b5951d10a91a0a7b56;
RANDOM=266284790:1466147978:c91d0896bac59e0b;
PHPSESSID=9ecb5156cf8fc3190fbc69fd13393243;
RANDOM=265078219%3A1463147975%3Ad0448d163e9b2123
```

duplicated entries... when after that I manually set again e.g. RANDOM with `setCookie`:

```
PHPSESSID=dba4ff392agd39b5951d10a91a0a7b56; 
RANDOM=111111111:2222222222:33333336bac59e0b;
PHPSESSID=9ecb5156cf8fc3190fbc69fd13393243; 
RANDOM=265078219%3A1463147975%3Ad0448d163e9b2123
```

values set by `WebView` are not overwritten, only my "manually" entered... how to force `WebView` to use my earlier set cookie OR overwrite already set?

Comment: Have you found the reason of this behaviour?

Comment: I've ended up with checking on (first) start that cookie exists, if not then I'm opening `WebView` (created "dynamicly" in `Activity` by `new WebView(this)`, size 1x1) with url, which is intended only to set cookie. after that inside app I'm using this cookie for webapi requests. not so well fixed IMHO, but I didn't found better solution :/

Answer (score 3):

As in [the MDN docs about `Set-Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) you can see many different kinds of cookie values, a cookie can be set to particular `Path`

> cookie-name=cookie-value; Path=path-value

And in `CookieManager.setCookie` `void setCookie (String url, String value)`, the [android reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setCookie(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) says:

> Sets a cookie for the given URL. Any existing cookie with the same **host**, **path** and **name** will be replaced with the new cookie. The cookie being set will be ignored if it is expired.

In my opinion, the reason that you have duplicate entries is because the cookie values were in different `Path`. So if you want to overwrite you should make sure **host path name** are the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void setCookieManager(String auth_token) {
    CookieSyncManager manager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
    cookieManager.setCookie(auth_token);

    manager.sync();
}
```

I think you just didn't setup your cookie manager properly. Give this a try

Comment: I'm currently giving this a try like above... I don't want to `removeSessionCookie();`, it should be kept, and I'm syncing  (`manager.sync();`) after every manual insertion and in `onPause` in activites with `WebView`